# The assertExactEquals is not working as expected for errors Ballerina testing

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

This happened while I was writing some tests and below is a sample code.

`main.bal`

```
public function testError() returns error? {
    io:println("testError executed");
    return error("Error occurred");
}
```

`test.bal`

```
@test:Config {}
function testErrorFunction() {
    test:assertExactEquals(testError(), error("Error occurred"));
}
```

`Result`

```
error {ballerina/test:0}TestError ("Assertion Failed!
 
expected: 'error("Error occurred")'
actual    : 'error("Error occurred")'")
    callableName: createBallerinaError moduleName: ballerina.test.0 fileName: assert.bal lineNumber: 41
    callableName: assertExactEquals moduleName: ballerina.test.0 fileName: assert.bal lineNumber: 170
```

It seems the assertExactEquals is unable to compare the actual and expected error objects.
Note: the actual error contains some additional characters "double quote" and parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour of `assertExactEquals`.  It checks if the two values are exactly referring to the same and are not just similar values. In this case the error returned by `testError` and the error created within   `testErrorFunction`  are two different values with the same error message, hence the assertion fails.

The confusion here seems to be due to the quotation marks. In the output

```
("Assertion Failed!
 
expected: 'error("Error occurred")'
actual    : 'error("Error occurred")'")
,
```

The last double quote is the closing of the double quote opened immediately after the opening parentheses in the first line `("Assertion Failed!`.

Instead of `assertExactEquals`, you can use `assertEquals` as follows,

```
function testErrorFunction() {
    error? err = testError();
    test:assertTrue(err is error);
    test:assertEquals((<error>err).message(), "Error occurred", "Error message is not same");
}
```

You can check the following documentations for more details on this

[1] https://ballerina.io/learn/test-ballerina-code/write-tests/#use-assertions

[2] https://central.ballerina.io/ballerina/test/latest#assertEquals